# Google SignIn fails when serverClientID specified

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I've got a server that interacts with Google Calendar on behalf of user. To do this it should obtain one-time access token from iOS application. I've referred to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/offline-access?hl=en), but have some issues with sign in.

I have started from "SignIn" example app (pod test Google > Sign In), provided it with my credentials (GoogleServices-Info.plist, bundleId). Then I signed it with my provision and started on iPhone 6, everything works like a charm.

Then I have added

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = @"<my-server-client-id>";
```

in **ViewController:viewDidLoad**. I have unauthorised in app, launched it again. It opened auth screen (youtube.app, 10.31.11670) again, I selected the same account, but this time it launched my app without displaying permissions screen, `-signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:` method was called, but `GIDGoogleUser` was nil. Error stated

> Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-1 "A potentially recoverable error occured. You may try again." UserInfo=0x17026af80 {NSLocalizedDescription=A potentially recoverable error occured. You may try again.}

I have tried several times, but each time I have received the same result. But if I comment `...serverClientID...` it begins to work again.

Then I have launched this app in simulator and it authorised successfully using WebView and I received `user.serverAuthCode`.
I decided that problem was in YouTube.app, I uninstalled it from device, but the same problem happened with other Google applications.

Could you point me what is wrong with my singIn implementation?

**PS**
Finally I decided to use workaround and rewrote `-canOpenUrl:` in UIApplication subclass this way:

```
- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"com-google-gidconsent"] || [[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"com.google.gppconsent"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canOpenURL:url];
}
```

And now it uses WebView authorisation and I can receive my one-time token. But this approach is crappy of course.

Comment: were you able to figure out the issue? I am seeing the same thing and I really don't want to fall back onto the web view flow if the user has already gone through the trouble of installing the Google app. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I leaved this feature as is, because this is not so important for my app. I also created issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/51), you can subscribe to it to be notified if it will be fixed.